# Expressibility of transitive closure on finite structures

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> Show that there is no formula of first-order logic which expresses
>   "$(a, b)$ is in the transitive closure of $R$", even on finite
>   structures.

I know how to prove the result for infinite structures using the compactness theorem. My idea for the finite case: use Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games to show that for each $n \in \omega$ no formula of quantifier depth $n$ expresses transitive closure. Concretely, add constants $a, b$ to  the language and find pairs of (finite) graphs $G_n^1, G_n^2$ such that

1. $a$ is connected to $b$ in $G_n^1$.
2. $a$ is not connected to $b$ in $G_n^2$.
3. Player II (the duplicator) has a winning strategy in the EF-game $\mathcal{G}_n(G_n^1, G_n^2)$ of length $n$.

The problem is that I cannot find such graphs.

Comment: What does "even on finite structures" mean precisely? I would interpret it as: there is no formula $\phi(x, y)$ such that for any finite structure $A$ we have $A \models \phi(a, b)$ if and only if $(a, b)$ in in the transitive closure of $R$ (where I assume $R$ is some binary relation on $A$). Also, I do not think EF games are going to work this way. The constant $a$ in $G_1$ will always have to be sent to $a$ in $G_2$, and similar for $b$.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Yes, that's how I've understood it as well.

Comment: "The constant $a$ in $G_1$ will always have to be sent to a in $G_2$, and similar for $b$." Sure, but why is that a problem? The proof that $M \equiv N$ if and only if player II has a winning strategy in $\mathcal{G}_n(M, N)$ goes through even if the language has a finite number of constants (I think), because the crucial property that the collection of formulas in $x$ with quantifier-depth at most $n$ is finite up to logical equivalence still holds.

Comment: Well, adding constants is not a problem for EF games in itself. It's just that player 1 will always win this game (at least, as you formulated it now). Player 1 can just pick $a$ first in $G_1$, then player 2 has to respond by $a$ in $G_2$. Similarly, player 1 can force player 2 to pick $b$ in $G_2$. If $a R b$ in $G_1$, but $a \not R b$ in $G_2$, then player 2 has already lost because the resulting map will fail to be a local isomorphism. By the way, I am not saying that EF games will not work at all, I have not yet really thought about an actual solution.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean (probably). Why would $aRb$ in $G_1$ or $G_2$? EDIT: Oh maybe I understand your objection, the graphs $G_1, G_2$ are not fixed for all $n$! I shall edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: You're right to use E-F games. For the $n$-round game, take $G_1$ to be a single cycle and $G_2$ to be the disjoint union of two cycles, probably of length $2^n$or maybe a little bigger, with $a$ and $b$ in different components of $G_2$. Duplicator's winning strategy is, at move $k$, to make sure all distances between chosen points are the same in $G_1$ and $G_2$ if they're $\leq2^{n-k}$. Distances bigger than $2^{n-k}$ in one graph should also be bigger than $2^{n-k}$ in the other, but they don't need to match exactly.

Comment: @Ibrahim I see now what you meant. Also, for some reason I first thought that by "$a$ connected to $b$" you meant "$aRb$" (my bad). Andreas already gave a solution sketch. The key point essentially being that you can make these graphs are so big, that from the point of view of the 'short' EF game, the cycles in the graph look linear. That is, during such an EF game, you can only consider a linear part of each cycle.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, I had the exact same idea, but I could not get it to work. I got it now (will post it as answer later); the problem was that for my solution $G_1, G_2$ need quite specific sizes, and not just be "large enough". If you don't get the relative sizes right there might be vertices infinitely far ($\geq 2^n$) away from both $a$ and $b$, which complicates the game strategy a lot (at least for me). Do you agree?